# how to restrict customer groups to use different paypal payment methods?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

**NOTE :**
i had tried this code which gets usergroup from backend .... and it works with checkmo and ccsave but doesn't work with paypal any method :(
can anyone tel me where i m wrong ?????

Comment: This question needs more detail, both in what you want and in what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You should extend all those methods and implement your checks in following method instead

```
public function isAvailable($quote = null)
```

Comment: can u plz explain ur answer ??

Comment: you are extending the wrong class and using the wrong method for what you a re trying to achieve